# Google Custom Search Accessibility

Tags: javascript, accessibility, google-custom-search

When we include Google Custom Search capability on our website, we get automatic code returned from Google containing some Google branding - images - that do not have alt tags for accessibility. I couldn't find a solution other than to write my own JavaScript to add alt tags to these images. Here is my solution, but my  question: is this something that we should or shouldn't do? I want to make sure all parts of the website pass accessibility tests.

```
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("gsc-branding-img");

for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
    if(x[i].tagName == "IMG") {
        x[i].alt = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tested this approach with screen readers? Does it actually provide a benefit?

Comment: If the images are conveying information, this approach would not result in an accessible application. You should add alts but you should make sure they are correct. Can you point to your web site of a jsfiddle?

Comment: @unobf here's the markup that gets generated by the Google Custom Search plugin https://jsfiddle.net/caydgr9k/

Comment: Thanks for providing the Google markup, I should have done that initially! One issue is we're hiding the image with CSS as the image doesn't make sense for our look and feel. See here: [www.santarosa.edu](http://www.santarosa.edu) The top search box is powered by GCSE, but we didn't want the Google logo to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The image in question is the Google logo, and it's presented as part of a phrase "powered by Google", where "Google" is the logo image. This phrase doesn't make sense to a screen reader user without alternative text.

Here's the section of the Google Custom Search plugin in question:

```html
      <td class="gsc-branding-text">
        <div class="gsc-branding-text">powered by</div>
      </td>
      <td class="gsc-branding-img">
        <img src="https://www.google.com/uds/css/small-logo.png" class="gsc-branding-img">
      </td>
```

Here's a variation on your solution to add alternative text to that image:

`document.querySelector('img.gsc-branding-img').alt = "Google"`

[view it at jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/caydgr9k/2/)

You could also add the text content to the parent tag and visually hide that text with CSS.

Comment: That is a MUCH cleaner version then what I've got, thanks! I'm still learning JS and jQuery, thanks for the help. Screen readers will be happier with an alt tag, even if it's empty, though I find it annoying we have to do this for CSS hidden images. Thanks! +1 vote from me!

Answer (score 0):

This article on [Making Google CSE Accessible](https://www.percussion.com/blog/2016/March/accessible-google-custom-search.html) was helpful in building a solution (for your same question) in a previous project I worked on.

You can build a callback like:

```
window.__gcse = {
  callback: imgAltTagsFix
};  

var imgAltTagsFix = function() {
  $('img.gsc-branding-img').attr("alt", "Google Custom Search Branding");
  $('input.gsc-search-button').attr('alt', "Google Custom Search Button");
};
```

Be sure to check out the [Using the JavaScript API to render elements](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/element) section for more details on how to expand this solution.